# What is a Serre presentation of a Lie algebra?

Tags: terminology, lie-algebras

For example, as in:

> Give a Serre presentation of Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ of type $G_{2}$.

Is it the presentation in terms of Chevalley generators, which satisfy Serre relations?

Comment: Where are you seeing the phrase? The quote sounds like a problem statement, in which case "Serre presentation" should be defined in the preceding text.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Nope, Serre presentation is not defined in the problem statement or anywhere else I looked (such as lecture notes).

Comment: Googling "serre presentation" gives a number of relevant results right away. I wouldn't be surprised if he describes this presentation in more detail in his book on semisimple Lie algebras.